# Multiple file upload method in PHP OOP

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, foreach

I am trying to build a method in **PHP** to upload multiple files into and insert the files names into a **MySQL** database.

I am trying to build this based on **PHP OOP**.

***Multiple issues I am facing and I have been stucking with this for more than 2 weeks.***

**First:** the method is only inserting 1 row into the database even if I selected multiple files in the form.

**Second:** the method is not getting the files name, so even if it inserts only 1 row, it inserts an empty row.

Here is the *images class*:

```
<?php
class Images extends Crud{
  protected static $db_table = "images";
  protected static $table_fields = array("id", "image_url", "property_id", "date");
  public $id;
  public $image_url;
  public $property_id;
  public $date;
  public $filename;
  public $tmp_path = array();
  public $upload_dir = "images";
  public $errors = array();
  public $upload_errors_array = array(
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK           => "There is no error.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => "The file size exceeds the upload_max_filesize",
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    => "The file upload exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE",
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR   => "Missing a temporary folder",
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE   => "Failed to write file on desk",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    => "A PHP extension stopped the file upload"
  );

  public function image_path(){
    return $this->upload_dir.DS.$this->image_url;
  }

  public function set_files($file){
    if(empty($file) || !$file || !is_array($file)){
      $this->errors[] = "There was no file uploaded here";
      return false;
    }else{
        $this->image_url = $file['name'];
        $this->tmp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
      }
  }
  public function new_images(){
    foreach ($_FILES['images'] as $file) {
      $this->set_files($file);
      $this->property_id    = "1";
      $this->date           = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $target_path = $this->upload_dir . DS . $this->image_url;
      move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_path, $target_path);
      if($this->create()){
        print_r($file);
        var_dump($file);
      return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

*`print_r` is showing the following:*

```
Array ( [0] => download (1).jpg [1] => download (2).jpg [2] => download (3).jpg [3] => download.jpg )
```

*and `var_dump` is showing the following:*

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(16) "download (1).jpg" [1]=> string(16) "download (2).jpg" [2]=> string(16) "download (3).jpg" [3]=> string(12) "download.jpg" }
```

**More details:**

Here is the main class which the *images class* extends from:

```
<?php
class Crud{
  protected static $db_table;
  public static function find(){
    return static::find_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table . "");
  }
  public static function find_limit($limit){
    return static::find_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table . " LIMIT " . $limit. "");
  }
  public static function find_id($id){
    global $database;
    $the_result_array = static::find_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table . " WHERE id='$id'");
    return !empty($the_result_array) ? array_shift($the_result_array) : false;
  }
  public static function find_query($sql){
    global $database;
    $set_result = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($set_result)){
      $object_array[] = static::instantiation($rows);
    }
    return $object_array;
  }
  public static function instantiation($records){
    $calling_class = get_called_class();
    $object = new $calling_class;
    foreach ($records as $attribute => $value) {
      if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
        $object->$attribute = $value;
      }
    }
    return $object;
  }
  private function has_attribute($attribute){
    $object_properties = get_object_vars($this);
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_properties);
  }
  protected function properties(){
    $properties = array();
    foreach (static::$table_fields as $field){
      if(property_exists($this, $field)){
        $properties[$field] = $this->$field;
      }
    }
    return $properties;
  }
  protected function clean_properties(){
    global $database;
    $clean_properties = array();
    foreach ($this->properties() as $key => $value) {
      $clean_properties[$key] = $database->escape_string($value);
    }
    return $clean_properties;
  }
  public function create(){
    global $database;
    $properties = $this->clean_properties();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".static::$db_table."(". implode(",", array_keys($properties)).")";
    $sql .= "VALUES ('". implode("','", array_values($properties)) ."')";
    if($database->query($sql)){
      $this->id = $database->last_id();
      print_r($sql);
      var_dump($sql);
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

*`print_r` is showing the following result:*

```
INSERT INTO images(id,image_url,property_id,date)VALUES ('','','1','2017-10-20 20:24:05')
```

*`var_dump` is showing the follwoing:*

```
string(89) "INSERT INTO images(id,image_url,property_id,date)VALUES ('','','1','2017-10-20 20:24:05')"
```

Furthermore, here is the **HTML** page:

```
<?php include_once "admin/head.php"; ?>
<?php if(!$session->is_signed_in()) {redirect("../index");}  ?>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $images = new Images();
   $images->new_images();
 }
 ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="images" class="control-label">نص الصورة البديل</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include "admin/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?" While I'm sure AhmadFramework and AhmadORM are something you've worked pretty hard on, these things can be extraordinarily difficult to get to the feature complete, tested and deployed state. That's why using an off-the-shelf solution is almost always a better call.

Comment: Well, it's more about learning, I know I can use ready frameworks, and there is a lot through the web, but my main target is to learn. Anyway, thank you so much for your suggestions. @tadman

Comment: I think learning is very important, and I'm the first to encourage people to explore and learn, but writing your own framework is extremely difficult and can be discouraging because of the exponential complexity factor as you add more features. It's much better to look at existing examples, use them until you're familiar with how they work, and then, *if* those still don't meet your needs and can't be adapted, write your own based on your experience with them.

Comment: This is the difference between someone learning to drive by building their own car out of parts they found in the junkyard without any input from those with experience, and someone driving a basic car with an instructor. Once you learn the basics you'll have opportunities to learn more about how the car works mechanically, as well as try your hand at more powerful vehicles. Same goes for code: Start with something adequate, explore how it works internally, and don't be afraid to try more advanced solutions.

Comment: So you mean I can still learn advanced skills even if I am using a ready framework. if so, I would go with that for sure. I am building a framework because I thought I can't sharpen my skills if I jumped immediately to a ready framework.

Comment: You'll have to pick a point in the technology stack to jump in and start. This is on the spectrum from individual atoms in your CPU, to the transistors, to the circuits, to the instruction set, to the low-level APIs, the OS, the scripting language, the framework, and the application you build with it. This is an *enormous* spread. Start with a framework and learn more about the underpinnings, work your way down, as well as work upwards by coming to understand [software design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) and software engineering principles.

Comment: There is no bottom to your learning, and there is no top. If you're the sort of person who wants to learn there will be *infinite opportunities* to learn more no matter where you start. The advantage of starting with a framework is simple: You get to learn from good examples, you get the support of the framework's community, and you can get more done in less time as you don't have to re-invent the wheel to get anything working.

Comment: @tadman Thanks man, you really navigated me to a better path, it's pretty hard to learn on your own, you get so lost with online tutorials and courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop through `$_FILES['images']` is wrong. Each element of this is not all the properties for a single file. Each element is a different property, which contains an array of those properties of all the uploads. E.g. `$_FILES['images']['name']` is an array of all the names. So you need to loop through one of these properties, and then get the corresponding elements of the other properties.

```
foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $index => $name) {
    $file = array('name' => $name, 'tmp_name' => $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$index]);
    $this->set_files($file);
    ...
}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, but its only uploading 1 file, I had to remove the following to be able to upload multiple files

`$this->id = $database->last_id();` `and return true;` from the `Crud` class and from the `Images` class

Thank you so much, I would appreciate it if you can explain to me why I had to remove the above statements to be able to upload multiple files.